# ¿Error en mostrar mensaje de error cuando todo devuelve cero?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un error en querer añadir un mensaje de error cuando no existen votos de algún producto.

Cuando no existen votos en algún producto toda las variables de la consulta devuelve el valor en impresión de `0` al parecer esta tomando el valor `0` como un dato valido como si fuera un voto de valor `0`

**¿Cómo puedo crear una condición a las variables o al `while ($stmt->fetch())` que si todo los valores de la consulta devuelve el valor `0` este muestre el mensaje de error?**

> **Nota:** Que la condición o parametro sólo se ejecute si toda la consulta de sus variables devuelve valor `0` si existe algún valor numérico de `0.5` no se ejecute.

```
$id_product = 1;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (4.5, 5) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM ratings
WHERE id_product=?");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($pct_5_star, $pct_4_star, $pct_3_star, $pct_2_star, $pct_1_star, $in_5_star, $avg_rating);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
    echo "4 estrellas " . number_format($pct_4_star). "% <br />";
    echo "3 estrellas " . number_format($pct_3_star). "% <br />";
    echo "2 estrellas " . number_format($pct_2_star). "% <br />";
    echo "1 estrellas " . number_format($pct_1_star). "% <br /><br />";
    echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
} else {
  echo "No existe votos de este producto";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero a ver entendido bien la pregunta.

Suma todos los las variables y si la suma es cero manda el error.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (($pct_1_star + $pct_2_star + $pct_3_star + $pct_4_star + $pct_5_star) == 0) {
         echo "No existe votos de este producto";
        continue;
    }
    echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
    echo "4 estrellas " . number_format($pct_4_star). "% <br />";
    echo "3 estrellas " . number_format($pct_3_star). "% <br />";
    echo "2 estrellas " . number_format($pct_2_star). "% <br />";
    echo "1 estrellas " . number_format($pct_1_star). "% <br /><br />";
    echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
}
```

Sin embargo si desde la consulta no deseas esos resultados usa `HAVING`

```
HAVING (pct_1_star +  pct_2_star + pct_3_star + pct_4_star + pct_5_star ) > 0
```

Asi:

```
SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (4.5, 5) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM ratings
WHERE id_product=?
HAVING (pct_1_star +  pct_2_star + pct_3_star + pct_4_star + pct_5_star ) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el cálculo de `AVG` que ya estas usando para obtener el promedio del resultado total, en caso que no encontró resultados la variable `$avg_rating` va ser `0` también, para ello creas una comprobación si dicha variable es mayor que `0` para mostrar tus resultados en caso contrario lanzas mensaje de error.

**Ejemplo:**

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //Si el promedio es mayor a 0, muestras resultados.
    if ($avg_rating > 0) {
        echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
        echo "4 estrellas " . number_format($pct_4_star). "% <br />";
        echo "3 estrellas " . number_format($pct_3_star). "% <br />";
        echo "2 estrellas " . number_format($pct_2_star). "% <br />";
        echo "1 estrellas " . number_format($pct_1_star). "% <br /><br />";
        echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
    } else { //Mensaje de error, el promedio dio 0 como resultado.
        echo "No existe votos de este producto";
    }

} 
$stmt->close();
```

Ahora también podrías calcular los votos emitidos, es decir, en caso que exista algún voto muestras las estadísticas en caso que no existe ningún voto, lanzas el mensaje de error.

De esta manera obtienes también el total de votos emitidos para tus estadísticas, simplemente he añadido a tu sentencia un cálculo más, `COUNT(*) votos`.

**Ejemplo alternativa:**

```
$id_product = 1;
//He añadido COUNT(*) votos
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (4.5, 5) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating,
       COUNT(*) votos
       FROM ratings
       WHERE id_product=?");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);
$stmt->execute();
//He añadido $votos para COUNT(*) votos.
$stmt->bind_result($pct_5_star, $pct_4_star, $pct_3_star, $pct_2_star, $pct_1_star, $in_5_star, $avg_rating,$votos);    

if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //Si existe algun voto, muestras estadísticas.
    if ($votos > 0) {

        echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
        echo "4 estrellas " . number_format($pct_4_star). "% <br />";
        echo "3 estrellas " . number_format($pct_3_star). "% <br />";
        echo "2 estrellas " . number_format($pct_2_star). "% <br />";
        echo "1 estrellas " . number_format($pct_1_star). "% <br /><br />";
        echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
        echo "<b>Total votos emitidos: $votos</b>";

    } else { //Existe 0 votos, muestras mensaje de error.
        echo "No existe votos de este producto";
    }

} 
$stmt->close();
```